# How to request AJAX concurrently with a HTTP request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In our current test plan we request a product page that contains AJAX. To get this AJAX data we use an xpath extractor, then build a new url path and request the ajax. The problem is we have a constant throughput timer which slows down these requests, when in reality we want them to all happen at once. Our test plan is as follows -

View Product Fragment

-HTTP Get Product Page
--build AJAX request
-HTTP Get AJAX information

Master Test File
-Call Product Fragment
-constant throughput timer (1 request per minute)

Is there any way to override the constant throughput timer from within the View Product Fragment?

I've tried nested controllers/timers but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a JSR223 Sampler or custom Sampler which won't respect JMeter Thread Group settings and will be able to fire off concurrent AJAX requests using it's own thread pool.

See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) guide for implementation details.

Comment: Great, thanks! I don't know how I missed this in the first place.

Sorry I can't upvote your answer, due to being a newbie :(

Answer (score 0):

I've added some info regarding a custom sampler that I found on github to this question:

[Performance Testing of AJAX calls via JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641045/performance-testing-of-ajax-calls-via-jmeter/39848230#39848230)

It is working very nicely for me.