# How to make ajax calls by using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a game website to do the load testing, but I need to do load testing of scoreboard, which is an Ajax call and changes dynamically.

I have tried to do this by using Groovy language and jsr223 sampler, but it's not working. Then I tried using the web driver sampler. I am unable to do it in both cases.
By using the web driver, a new browser gets launched every time and it's unable to do load testing by simulating 100 or more users.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you have look over basic tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Please take an help from below:
https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter

[Performance Testing of AJAX calls via JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641045/performance-testing-of-ajax-calls-via-jmeter)